# How to generate TS streams from middle of a source video?

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming

I am using ffmpeg to create m3u8 playlist for a video (actually a live video stream). I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i /home/ubuntu/Download/1459530099245.mkv -c:a aac -strict experimental -ac 2 -ar 48k -ab 64k -c:v libx264 -s 480x270 -aspect 16:9 -b:v 400k -r 15 -g 45 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -f hls -hls_time 9 -hls_list_size 0  /home/ubuntu/Download/New Playlist.m3u8
```

It produces m3u8 file as well as ts files.

Question: simply, how can we produce m3u8 playlist and TS files for a particular duration of source video? E.g., I want to get playlist only for first 20 seconds or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command `-to`. Just add `-to 00:00:20` after input path
In your variant:

```
ffmpeg -i /home/ubuntu/Download/1459530099245.mkv -to 00:00:20 -c:a aac -strict experimental -ac 2 -ar 48k -ab 64k -c:v libx264 -s 480x270 -aspect 16:9 -b:v 400k -r 15 -g 45 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -f hls -hls_time 9 -hls_list_size 0 /home/ubuntu/Download/New Playlist.m3u8
```

More information here: http://www.bogotobogo.com/FFMpeg/ffmpeg_seeking_ss_option_cutting_section_video_image.php

Comment: When i run this command it gives 'Bitrate: N/A'
Do you know how to give bitrate option in the command ?

Comment: Strangely, I tried the command that I suggested to you (but with mp4 files) and it is work. Actually, this part of command `-b:v 400k` set bitrate of output file. What size of your input file?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a php script along with a server that does what you need. Replicate the files or recreate al the .ts files locally then you can manipulate them for 20 seconds, 20 hours, or whatever you need to play. Something like this

```
$newlist= fopen("/www/data/tv/yournewplaylist.m3u8", "a");
$newsecuencia1=($secuencia)+0;
$newsecuencia2=($secuencia)+1;
$newsecuencia3=($secuencia)+2;
$newsecuencia4=($secuencia)+3;
$newsecuencia5=($secuencia)+4;
$data="#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:".$secuencia.PHP_EOL."#EXTINF:3.000000,".PHP_EOL."http://yourlocalserver/newvideofile".$newsecuencia1.".ts".PHP_EOL;
//... whatevere else you need in your list file 
fwrite($newlist,$data);
fclose($newlist);`enter code here`
```

Do not create a new m3u8, you need to append to it, otherwise will reload de video all the time. Do not use **#EXT-X-ENDLIST** You need to delete everyday de m3u8 file to create a small one. Great help your post. Thank you.